# Is this an efficient prime number proof algorithm?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I’m not a mathematician but I love algorithms and as many before me I’ve fallen in love with the prime numbers. I thought of an algorithm for proving a number is prime but I cannot access its complexity. I only know for any n in the worst-case scenario it makes some $\sqrt{n}$ checks (I guess, for 25 takes 3 iterations, for 11 takes 2, if it's relevant). The algorithm goes as follows:

1) let $ h = 2, w = n/h$ (truncated result), $r$ = $ n$ mod h (remainder)

2) if $r = 0\implies$ it’s not a prime number (we’re done with the check), else let h = h + 1, $d = w - r$, $p = d/h$ and $pr$ = $d$ mod h

3) if $pr = 0\implies$ not a prime number, r = h - pr,  h = h + 1, w = w – (p + 1)
we go to 2) and repeat until r = 0 or h = $\sqrt{n}$ + 1
If we reach h = $\sqrt{n}$ + 1 and still have r > 0, it means the number is prime.

I’m sorry for the lame question and the probably invalid mathematical notation used. I’m neither a native speaker nor mathematician but I’ll be happy to receive some feedback on the validity/complexity of the algorithm above. Thank you in advance for your time!

Example:

n = 25

h = 2

w = n/h = 12

r = n mod h = 1

r > 0 => h = h + 1 = 3

d = w – r =12 – 1 = 11

p = d/h = 11/3 = 3

pr = d mod h = 2

pr > 0 => r = h – pr = 3 – 2 = 1

h = h + 1 = 3 +1 = 4

w = w – (p + 1) = 12 – (3 + 1) = 8

step 2)

r > 0 => h = h + 1 = 4 + 1 = 5

d = w – r = 8 – 3 = 7

p = d/h = 7/4 = 1

pr = d mod h = 3

pr > 0 => r = h – pr = 4 – 3 = 1

h = h + 1 = 4 + 1 = 5

w = w – (p + 1) = 8 – (1 + 1) = 6

step 2)

r > 0 => h = h + 1 = 5 + 1 = 6

d = w – r = 6 – 1 = 5

p = d/h = 5/5

pr = d mod h = 5 mod 5 = 0

pr = 0 => not a prime

Comment: See the paper [Primes is in P](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Rohan Thanks for the paper, it's a much more efficient algorithm. As for the algorithm above - it's not optimal, but as a side effect it may serve as a sieve if we choose big enough n and store all w*h values as non-prime numbers up to n.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, I've formatted the square root sign, the rest is ok, I hope.

Comment: Can you write something about what the intuition about those computations are? In particular I find it difficult to see what the significance of $w-r$ is.

Comment: @HenningMakholm w - r is the remainder to the nearest higher than n number, divisible by h. Perhaps remainder is not the right word, it's a result of substraction: h*w - n.

Comment: @TanyaM: From where? The first time around the loop, $d$ is about half of $n$. I don't see how to interpret that as a "remainder".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Just a moment, I'm new to stackexchange and it doesn't allow me to edit comments later than 5 min after post. I'll write it complete first and then post it.

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm does not work. Suppose we want to check if $n=11$ is a prime. Then it makes the following assignments:

- $h\leftarrow 2$.
- $w\leftarrow \lfloor 11/2 \rfloor = 5$.
- $r\leftarrow 11\bmod 2 = 1$.
- ($r$ is not $0$, so we continue).
- $d\leftarrow 5-1 = 4$.
- $p\leftarrow \lfloor 4/2\rfloor = 2$.
- $pr \leftarrow 4\bmod 2 = 0$.
- Since $pr=0$ the algorithm declares $11$ to be not a prime, which is wrong.

I suspect you have a typo somewhere, so what you have written is not actually the computation you had in mind -- but it is difficult to guess based on the question what you actually had in mind.

In any case it appears to be clear that the algorithm is supposed to perform $\sqrt n$ iterations of the loop when $n$ *is* prime, since you only increase $h$ by one at a time. Even if the details are fixed so you get a *correct* primality test, the result cannot reasonably be called an *efficient* one. If you want to verify a 100-digit prime (which is a routine task these days) you would need to run about $10^{50}$ iterations of the loop!

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just found the mistake myself, I'll post the edit and a short example in a while.

Comment: I've just posted the correction and added the example. You are right about efficiency, but if we store the w*h values we would have a sieve for all non-primary numbers < n.

Answer (score 0):

With corrected algorithm for 11 it goes like:

n = 11

h = 2

w = n/h = 5

r = n mod h = 1

r > 0 => h = h + 1 = 3

d = w – r = 5 – 1 = 4

p = d/h = 4/3 = 1

pr = d mod h = 1

pr > 0 => r = h – pr = 3 – 1 = 2

h = h + 1 = 3 +1 = 4

w = w – (p + 1) = 5 – (1 + 1) = 3

step 2)

r > 0 => h = h + 1 = 4 + 1 = 5

d = w – r = 3 – 2 = 1

p = d/h = 1/5 = 0

pr = d mod h = 5

pr > 0 => r = h – pr = 4 – 5 = -1

h = h + 1 = 4 +1 = 5

h > $\sqrt{11}$ + 1 => prime

I guess negative r is enough of an evidence and the latest check is not needed